# NSUserDefaults for Today Extension not saving data, iOS swift. Can't figure out what I am doing wrong here

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults, today-extension

I am trying to share [[String:String]] object between my app and Today Extension.

In my app, I am saving an object like this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    // Save all data and update Today Extension
    // 1) Save selectedStations as Dictionary to NSUserDefaults
    if var sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.xxx.xxx") {
        // Save to userDefaults (1) stationName, (2) stationLine, (3) id, (4) statnId, (5) subwayId
        var arrayOfDic:[[String:String]] = []
        for station in selectedStations {
            // Organize data to pass to widget
            let name: String     = station.name     ?? ""
            let line: String     = station.line     ?? ""
            let id: String       = station.id       ?? ""
            let statnId: String  = station.statnId  ?? ""
            let subwayId: String = station.subwayId ?? ""

            // Create dictionary
            let dic = [
                "name"     : name,
                "line"     : line,
                "id"       : id,
                "statnId"  : statnId,
                "subwayId" : subwayId
            ]

            // Append to array
            arrayOfDic.append(dic)
        }
        // Save to NSUserDefaults
        sharedDefaults.setObject(arrayOfDic, forKey: "selectedStations")
        println("    saved:\(arrayOfDic)")
        sharedDefaults.synchronize()
    }
    // 2) Refresh Today Extension
}
```

And within the same .swift file, I am retrieving the data in 'ViewDidLoad' like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if var sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.xxx.xxx") {
        sharedDefaults.synchronize()
        if let arrayOfDic = NSUserDefaults().objectForKey("selectedStations") as? [[String:String]] {
            println("   fetched:\(arrayOfDic)")
        }
    }
}
```

But I realize that

```
println("    saved:\(arrayOfDic)")
```

logs what I am trying to save, but

```
println("   fetched:\(arrayOfDic)")
```

is not logging anything. This part seems to be nil:

```
if let arrayOfDic = NSUserDefaults().objectForKey("selectedStations") as? [[String:String]]
```

Is my code wrong??

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this line of code:

```
if var sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.xxx.xxx")
```

Think again what are you actually doing in here? You are creating a new instance of NSUserDefaults. While what you need is to get reference of the one created in viewWillDisappear method.

My suggestion would be is to implement 
sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.xxx.xxx")  outside of both functions (make it lets say instance variable)

and later on in viewDidLoad implement the following:

```
if let sharedDefaults = sharedDefaults
```

instead of `sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.xxx.xxx")`